# I need help for a simple Countif into an Arrayformula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, counting, countif

I am trying to transpose this formula into an Arrayformula but I am stucked.

```
=COUNTIF($C$3:C3;C3)
```

Can someone help me, please?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gH1_8vnKUNDr0JtETjxJtD82cb5FWHQCAgMeebkebYU/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TRIM(C3:C)="",,COUNTIFS(C3:C, C3:C, ROW(C3:C), "<="&ROW(C3:C))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, player0!